# How to remove a git branch in Netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I am using Netbeans 8 with Git plugin. I have a branch that I would like to delete, but I don't see an option for that. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: _Generally in Git you can delete a branch from a remote repository with the push command and specifying a certain attribute to it. True that's not possible in the IDE either, but i have no plans to implement it since i consider this a not widely used feature and not worth the effort. Just use commandline for branch removal_ https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209644

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's how I proceed in Netbeans 8.1 (without using the terminal):

1. Team -> Repository -> Repository browser.
2. Repository browser is opened on the bottom. Go Branches -> Local (or Remote, depending on which one you need to delete).
3. Select the branch you want to delete, right click on it, and choose Delete option.

[image]

I know I'm late, but I hope it'll help somebody in the future.

Footnote: Make sure you're not currently active in the branch you want to delete as the delete option will be greyed out. Switch to another branch then you can delete the one you need.